# expected result from 'map' not getting

Tags: python

I expect to get the following result but i cant. can anyone help?
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14, 16, 18], [20, 22, 24]]

```
A=[]
B=[]
C=[]

lst = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12] ]  

for A in lst:

    B = list(map(lambda x=B : x*2 for B in A , A)
    C.append(B)

print(C)
```

Comment: for A in lst:
    C = [[lambda x:x * 2 for x in B] for B in A]
print(C)

it gives error:  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: I guess @luk2302 meant: `C = [[x * 2 for x in B] for B in lst]`

Comment: I get error with your code:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: thanks swifty it works.

Comment: You're welcome; in the future, keep in mind that using list comprehension if generally easier than using `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lst = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12] ]
```

If you want to keep your initial approach:

```
C=[]
for A in lst:
    B = list(map(lambda x : x*2 , A))
    C.append(B)

print(C)
```

A simpler way to do it:

```
C=[]
for A in lst:
    B = [x*2 for x in A]
    C.append(B)

print(C)
```

And even more simply, using [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
C = [[x*2 for x in B] for B in lst]

print(C)
```